# Deploy Express app with Terraform in Lambda

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Please help me on deploying express.js app on lambda using terraform. As i cannot see much info regarding that, but i can see a lot of articles that uses serverless framework instead of terraform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `terraform-aws-lambda` [module](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-lambda) to start. If you need guidance on Terraform for HTTP API Gateways, these example is under the API Gateway Terraform is [a good start](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-apigateway-v2/tree/master/examples/complete-http).